# Closing a custom alert dialog on button click

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I'm having trouble closing my alert dialog. I am using a layout inflator to make the dialog, so I'm not sure how I would go about closing the thing after I'm done with it. Code is below:

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(AddData.this);
DialogInterface dia = new DialogInterface();

//Create a custom layout for the dialog box
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)AddData.this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_rep_1_set, parent, false);

TextView title = (TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.rep_1_title);
Button add_item = (Button)layout.findViewById(R.id.add_button);

add_item.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
        //Need this to close the alert dialog box
        }
});

title.setText(workout_items[position]);
dialog.setView(layout);
dialog.show();
```

I cant call finish, because that closes the listview that the alert dialog is launched from, and the dialog.dismiss calls are not available to me.

What do you think I should do to fix this?

Answer (score 49):

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(AddData.this);
DialogInterface dia = new DialogInterface();

//Create a custom layout for the dialog box
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)AddData.this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_rep_1_set, parent, false);

TextView title = (TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.rep_1_title);
Button add_item = (Button)layout.findViewById(R.id.add_button);

title.setText(workout_items[position]);
dialog.setView(layout);

AlertDialog alertDialog = dialog.create();

add_item.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        alertDialog.dismiss();
    }
});


alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: Variable alertDialog is accessed from within inner class. Needs to be declared final.

Comment: What is `DialogInterface dia` for?

Answer (score 18):

Try this:

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.brush_opts_dialog,null);

    builder.setView(dialogView);


    closeBtn = (Button)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.close_btn);


   final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

    closeBtn .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    dialog.show();
```

You should use the AlertDialog.Builder to "build" the Alert Dialog itself. Then, call the create() method on the AlertDialog.Builder object. This method returns an AlertDialog object, which allows you to call dismiss().

You should not have to create it multiple times, nor use any DialogInterface objects. This works for me. Let me know how it goes for you.

Comment: Your explanation to call the create() was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 16):

do it like this,

```
add_item.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 3):

**i have modified your code plz check..**

```
   AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(AddData.this);
    DialogInterface dia = new DialogInterface();

    //Create a custom layout for the dialog box
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)AddData.this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_rep_1_set, parent, false);

    TextView title = (TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.rep_1_title);
    Button add_item = (Button)layout.findViewById(R.id.add_button);



    final AlertDialog Dial = alertDialog.create();
    title.setText(workout_items[position]);
    Dial.setView(layout);

    AlertDialog alertDialog = dialog.create();

    add_item.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Dial.dismiss();
        }
    });


    Dial.show();
```

**Just Added**

> final AlertDialog Dial = alertDialog.create();
>   and change 
>   **dialog.setView(layout);**
>   to 
>   **Dial.setView(layout);**

now just call **Dial.dismiss();** in onclick listener..
works fine for me.

Comment: @Abdus.. WHY YOU call create(); two times?

Answer (score 2):

use this code in your class:

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom);
((Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button))
   .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
});
dialog.show();
```

and create custom.xml, then paste this code inside it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=" Ok "/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

source: https://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/

> and if you do not like above code, so see below link:
>   http://thedeveloperworldisyours.com/android/prevent-alertdialog-closing-button-clicked/

Answer (score 0):

Try dialog.cancel(); in your onclick listener. 
 It should work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement DialogInterface.OnClickListener rather than View.OnClickListener. then dialog.dismiss() will be available.

```
new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
       dialog.dismiss();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You get error, Try this code**

```
   dialog.setView(layout);

   final AlertDialog alertDialog = dialog.create();

   add_item.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
     public void onClick(View v)
        {
          if (alertDialog != null && alertDialog.isShowing()) {
              alertDialog.dismiss();
        }
      }
    });
   alertDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     final viewProgressDialogue viewProgressDialogue = new viewProgressDialogue(DebugActivity.this);
        viewProgressDialogue.show();
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.d("response","im calling");
                viewProgressDialogue.dismiss();
            }
        }, 5000);
```

> ```
> > Make it one Instance so that it will work
> It Will in the Fragment too.
>
> for Fragment Use
> ```

```
    final viewProgressDialogue viewProgressDialogue = new viewProgressDialogue(getActivity());
        viewProgressDialogue.show();
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.d("response", "im calling");
                viewProgressDialogue.dismiss();
            }
        }, 5000);
```

> ```
> > viewProgressDialogue Class
> ```

```
public class viewProgressDialogue extends Dialog {
    public viewProgressDialogue(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);

        WindowManager.LayoutParams wlmp = getWindow().getAttributes();
        getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
        wlmp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
        getWindow().setAttributes(wlmp);
        setTitle(null);
        setCancelable(false);
        setOnCancelListener(null);

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
                R.layout.custom_progress, null);
        setContentView(view);


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a little change from above answers that just check that if you have written **AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();** before **builder.setView(...);** method, then just write it after **builder.setView(...);**

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
btn_go_anyway.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        getDialog().dismiss();
    }
});
```