# Make a popup that displays a random image then closes when clicked on

Tags: android, eclipse, image, button, popup

I am working on a program in which I would like to click on a button and have a popup window appear in the middle of the screen displaying a random image.  Then upon clicking the popup window it closes the popup.

my question is this possible?  if so how?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. For further help you would need to find a more specific question.

Answer (score 1):

yes you cant. for that you would need to create a [Custom Alert dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044793/popupwindow-with-image) which inflates a layout with an imageview in it and call it on clicking the desired object. also you will need to set an onlick listener by adding a [close button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713312/closing-a-custom-alert-dialog-on-button-click) to the AlertDialog to close it.

Comment: sure. if it works, please up vote and accept answer to close the thread. and if it doesn't, keep asking.

Comment: i have now successfully gotten... very confused... and an app that crashes when i try to open it...

Comment: can you put the logcat for the crash here?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could use something like this:

```
Dialog confirmDeleteDialog = new Dialog(this);
confirmDeleteDialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_message_dialog);
//This allows dialog to be closed with back button
confirmDeleteDialog.setCancelable(true);
//DisplayMetrics will get the screen dimensions and allow you to 
//declare a center point
DiaplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
int screenHeight = displaymetrics.heightPixels; //Divide by 2 to get mid
int screenWidth = displaymetrics.widthPixels; //Divide by 2 to get mid

Button closeButton = (Button) confirmDeleteDialog.findViewById(R.id.close_button);
closeButton.setOnClickListener(this);
confirmDeleteDialog.show();
```

custom_message_dialog.xml - could look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<Button
android:id="@+id/close_button"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:clickable="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The ClickListener

```
public void onClick(View v) {
if(v == closeButton){
confirmDeleteDialog.dismiss();
}}
```